# Bluetooth icon inside iOS status bar

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth

I am trying to develop a Swift program connecting to the bluetooth device. However I have encountered a problem that the bluetooth icon inside the iOS status bar will not be changed, no matter the device is connected or not.
Is there any method to indicate the bluetooth connection from the status bar icon, similar to Android device, where

connected: [image]

disconnected: [image]

Comment: You have no control over the status bar, except for setting up its appearance : visible/not visible and black/white.

Comment: BLE connections don't affect the Bluetooth icon in the iOS status bar.

Comment: I don't want to be rude.. but it's well documented on Apple docs...

Comment: Hi ingconti, would you mind Kindly show me the Apple docs for controlling the bluetooth icon?